# On sleep, open processes are closed

Tags: 11.10, gnome, suspend, process, sleep

I am using a DELL Inspiron 1525.

I have setup close-lid to sleep mode. On waking up from sleep, all my previously open processes have been closed and I am shown a blank desktop.

Any known solutions to this?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you set it to shutdown instead.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are suffering from [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/882956). The solution provided in the comments works for me (also a Inspiron 1525) so far.

The solution from [erny(erevilla)](https://launchpad.net/~erevilla):

```
 * Create a file /etc/pm/sleep.d/50_custom with the following content:

 --8<-- cut --8<-- cut --8<-- cut --8<-- cut --8<-- cut --8<-- cut --8<--
 #!/bin/sh

 # Action script to shutdown modules before suspending.
 # before a hibernate
 #
 # Copyright: Copyright (c) 2009 Ernesto Revilla
 # License: GPL-2
 #

 PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

 case "${1}" in
    suspend|suspend_hybrid|hibernate)
        rmmod uvcvideo
        rmmod usbhid
        rmmod psmouse
            ;;

    resume|thaw)
        modprobe uvcvideo
        modprobe usbhid
        modprobe psmouse
            ;;

 esac

 --8<-- cut --8<-- cut --8<-- cut --8<-- cut --8<-- cut --8<-- cut --8<--
```

Now the script has to be made executable:

```
 sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/50_custom
```